# vue-router: skip page when using browser back button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a "Home" page and a "Success" page in my application.

The Success page has a button that, when clicked, goes to a URL like `https://google.com`, via `window.location.href='https://google.com'`.

I can start on the Home page, use vue-router to push to the Success page, and then click the button to go to the URL. However, when I press the browser's back button, I'd like it to go back to the Home page instead of the Success page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your javascript is within a Vue instance, you can add a call to `$router.replace` right before setting `window.location.href`.

It would look something like this:

```
methods: {
  onLinkClick() {
    this.$router.replace({ name: 'home' }); // or whatever your home page name is
    window.location.href='https://google.com';
  }
}
```

Here's the documentation for [vue-router programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html).