# Vue-router: How to go back two same routes in history stack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, html5-history

I am using Vue 2.x.

There is a post page. When I click on a button in the post page, I go to the edit page. And when I click submit on the edit page, I used `this.$route.replace(link_to_post_page)` in order to remove the edit page from the history stack, and push the post page.

So now I have two of the same routes(the post page) in my history stack.

The problem is, when I click on the browser's back button, I go to the same page, that is, the post page. This is a very unnatural flow of pages for the user, and I want to fix it.

I have researched on ways to fix this for 6 hours, however I failed to find the solution.

My first try was to use Navigation Guards. But Navigation Guards only work when the route changes. In my case, the route does not change.

I also tried using window.history.onPopState event listener but failed with that too, because I could not manipulate the route when using window.history.onPopState.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

P.S.
The most similar question on Stack Overflow is this [vue-router: skip page when using browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683412/vue-router-skip-page-when-using-browser-back-button) but it does not answer my question at all. I have checked other questions but they also don't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not going back in the history instead of pushing a new `/edit` route?

| Steps | Routes stack |
| --- | --- |
| `/post` | ['post'] |
| -> Click on "edit" button |  |
| `/edit` | ['post', 'edit'] |
| -> `this.$router.back()` |  |
| `/post` | ['post', <s>'edit'</s>] |

The drawback of this is that the user still can manually go forward to the `/edit` page.
But if they go on another page, it will override the next steps (the `/edit` route above on the stack)

Comment: I need to make the website perfect, so it should not go forward to the `/edit` page after editing. So, yeah, the drawback is quite significant.

Comment: I get it. But I don't find any perfect solution for this...   
You could try not make the `/edit` page a real page if you don't want the router to even 
consider it. (Use a query param instead?).   
Or you replace the current `/post` by `/edit`, then replace again `/edit` to `/post`. That double replace will achieve what you want I guess (but still has drawbacks).

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be no perfect solution. But your idea of making /edit not a real page seems to be a nice idea, something that I could get the answer from.